# Evaluating rational algebraic expression

Tags: algebra-precalculus, rational-functions

If $x=1+\sqrt{3},$ find the value of $\dfrac{2x^2-4x+8}{3x^2-6x+10}.$

Comment: Faster than what?

Comment: A faster way than *what*?

Comment: probably direct substitution

Comment: @DietrichBurde: Great minds think together ;o)

Comment: Aside from direct substitution

Comment: Remember that $(1+\sqrt{3})^2 = 1 + 2 \sqrt{3} + 3$ and keep the radical until the end.

Comment: @Dietrich Burde Faster than you can close the question, and two answers show that's possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The equation is

$$\frac{2 \cdot (x-1)^2 + 6}{3 \cdot (x-1)^2 + 7} = 12/16 = 3/4$$

Answer (score 3):

$(x-1)^2=3$ so $x^2= 2x+2$ so:

$$\dfrac{2x^2-4x+8}{3x^2-6x+10} =\dfrac{4x+4-4x+8}{6x+6-6x+10} ={3\over 4}$$